# How to insert a specific character at a specific line of a file using sed or awk?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I want to use command to edit the specific line of a file instead of using vi. This is the thing. If there is a `#` starting with the line, then replace the `#` to make it uncomment. Otherwise, add the `#` to make it comment. I'd like to use sed or awk. But it won't work as expected.
This is the `file`.

```
what are you doing now?
what are you gonna do? stab me?
this is interesting.
This is a test.
go big
don't be rude.
```

For example, I just want to add the `#` at the beginning of the the line 4 `This is a test` if it doesn't start with `#`. And if it starts with `#`, then remove the `#`.

I've already tried via sed & gawk (awk)

```
gawk -i inplace '$1!="#" {print "#",$0;next};{print substr($0,3,length-1)}' file
```

```
sed -i /test/s/^#// file  # make it uncomment

sed -i /test/s/^/#/ file  # make it comment
```

I don't know how to use `if else` to make `sed` work. I could only make it with a single command, then use another regex to make the opposite.
Using gawk, it works as the main line. But it will mess the rest of the code up.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '4{s/^/#/;s/^##//}' file
```

On line 4 prepend a `#` to the line and if there 2 `#`'s remove them.

Could also be written:

```
sed '4s/^/#/;4s/^##//' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This will remove `#` from the start of line 4 or add it if it wasn't already there:

```
sed -i '4s/^#/\n/; 4s/^[^\n]/#&/; 4s/^\n//' File
```

The above assume GNU `sed`.  If you have BSD/MacOS `sed`, some minor changes will be required.

When sed reads a new line, the one thing that we know for sure about the new line is that it does *not* contain `\n`.  (If it did, it would be two lines, not one.)  Using this knowledge, the script works by:

- `s/^#/\n/`

  If the fourth line starts with `#`, replace `#` with `\n`.  (The `\n` serves as a notice that the line had originally been commented out.)
- `4s/^[^\n]/#&/`

  If the fourth line now starts with anything other than `\n` (meaning that it was not originally commented), put a `#` in front.
- `4s/^\n//`

  If the fourth line now starts with `\n`, remove it.

#### Alternative: Modifying lines that contain `test`

To comment/uncomment lines that contain `test`:

```
sed  '/test/{s/^#/\n/; s/^[^\n]/#&/; s/^\n//}' File
```

#### Alternative: using awk

The exact same logic can be applied using awk.  If we want to comment/uncomment line 4:

```
awk 'NR==4 {sub(/^#/, "\n"); sub(/^[^\n]/, "#&"); sub(/^\n/, "")} 1' File
```

If we want to comment/uncomment any line containing `test`:

```
awk '/test/ {sub(/^#/, "\n"); sub(/^[^\n]/, "#&"); sub(/^\n/, "")} 1' File
```

#### Alternative: using sed but without newlines

To comment/uncomment any line containing `test`:

```
sed  '/test/{s/^#//; t; s/^/#/; }' File
```

How it works:

- `s/^#//; t`

  If the line begins with `#`, then remove it.

  `t` tells sed that, if the substitution succeeded, then it should skip the rest of the commands.
- `s/^/#/`

  If we get to this command, that means that the substitution did not succeed (meaning the line was not originally commented out), so we insert `#`.

Comment: The `'\n'` is key. Otherwise you end up canceling what you did with expression 1 in expression 2 `:)` (as I found out ....)

Comment: Yes, @DavidC.Rankin. Thanks the hint from John. Lol. It took me 3 hours and I didn't figure it out until I posted the question here

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You and Alex got me thinking about it and an alternative (not using `\n`) is to use sed's test command `t` as shown in the method that I just added to the end of the answer.

Comment: That is indeed a cool trick and learning has occurred. I do recall seeing it somewhere in my perusing of the `sed` man or info page -- but obviously it never sank in. Just wish I could vote twice for it.

Comment: @John1024 It's amazing. Thanks for the hint again.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up on a system with a `sed` that doesn't support in-place editing, you can fall back to its uncle `ed`:

```
ed -s file 2>/dev/null <<EOF
4 s/^/#/
s/^##//
w
q
EOF
```

(Standard error is redirected to `/dev/null` because in `ed`, unlike `sed`, it's an error if `s` doesn't replace anything and a question mark is thus printed to standard error.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==4{$0=(sub(/^#/,"") ? "" : "#") $0} 1' file
what are you doing now?
what are you gonna do? stab me?
this is interesting.
#This is a test.
go big
don't be rude.

$ awk 'NR==4{$0=(sub(/^#/,"") ? "" : "#") $0} 1' file |
  awk 'NR==4{$0=(sub(/^#/,"") ? "" : "#") $0} 1'
what are you doing now?
what are you gonna do? stab me?
this is interesting.
This is a test.
go big
don't be rude.
```